# How can I refer to a data in a different row?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I've got an Excel file with N rows and M columns. Usually data are organized one per row, but it can happens that a data occupy more than a row. In this case how can I express that the second (or next) row has to refer to the first row?

[image]

In this example, AP.01 has got 5 rows of description, so how can I say that the other 4 rows refer also to the first code?

**EDIT** once that I did the association I have to export my Excel file into an Access DB. So I want to see the tables with the correct data.
If I have only one row for the description I wrote this code and it works:

```
If grid(r, 3).Text.Length > 255 Then
       code.Description = grid(r, 3).Text.ToString.Substring(0, 252) + "..."
       Else
          code.Description = grid(r, 3).Text.ToString
End If
```

Instead if I have more than one row for the description I wrote this code and it doesn't work:

```
Do While grid(r, 1).ToString = ""
                    If grid(r, 1).ToString = "" And grid(r, 3).ToString IsNot Nothing Then
                        Dim s As String
                        s = grid(r, 3).ToString
                        code.Description = grid((r - 1), 3).ToString & s
                    End If
                Loop
```

Comment: What have you tried? Your question is too vague to respond to without seeing either a) some code that you've attempted yourself or b) a much more detailed explanation of what you want to achieve.

Comment: What is `code.Description` and after assigning `code.Description = grid((r - 1), 3).ToString & s` what are you doing with `code.Description`, need to see more code.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a one-off, try the below. This will basically put a formula in every cell that refers to the cell immediately above it:

1. Select column A (from top until bottom of list (row N)
2. Press `ctrl` + `g` to open the GoTo dialogue
3. Press `Special`
4. Select `Blanks` from the radio buttons

The above will select all the blank cells in column A. Now enter `=` and press `up arrow`. Enter the formula by holding down `ctrl` while pressing enter. That will enter the same formula in every cell.

Comment: For something bound to recur, might be worth writing VBA to do similar.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")      'change Sheet3 to your data sheet
    With .Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I Guess that, you must be define a variable for last column Value. and check the value in respective column, if it  is empty then use column value if not empty  then take current value as last value.

'`Dim LastValue as string 
LastValue = sheet("SheetName").cells(i,"Column Name").value
for i = 2 to LastRow '>>>> here i am assume you run code in for loop from row to 
                           'to last count row(LastRow as variable)
'Put your sheet name at "SheetName" and column index (like "A","B","C"...) at "Column Name"
if sheet("SheetName").cells(i,"Column Name").value <>"" then
LastValue = sheet("SheetName").cells(i,"Column Name").value
end if
'(Do your stuff using LastValue , you may generate lastvalue 1, lastvalue2 ..etc)
next'for loop end here`